# How to have WebStorm know that the properties of one object are linked to a declaration in another file?

Tags: javascript, object, reference, webstorm

I'm working on a project that is designed in a way where the references for certain JavaScript objects are abstracted away from the files where they are declared and then available later as properties of a special object.

For example, let's say I have the following files:

- main.js
- content.js

JavaScript in **content.js** is run in a completely different context, but variables that were defined in **main.js** are accessible under a special object. For example, if we have the following in **main.js**...

```
exportOptions({
    name: "John Smith"
});
```

This information is available in **content.js** by calling...

```
self.options.name;
```

How can I let WebStorm know that `self.options.name` in **content.js** is linked to `name` from **main.js** WITHOUT adding any extra executable code to either JavaScript files?

Are there any WebStorm specific commands/instructions that can be written in JavaScript comments or JSDoc which WebStorm can use to form this link?

I'm mainly interested in finding a solution because I love being able to autocomplete and automatically inspect code for errors/warnings/typos. Right now, WebStorm throws warnings when `self.options.name` is used, for example, because it is undefined in `context.js`.

Edit:

I realize that I could instead do the following in **main.js**, but I'm still unsure how to have WebStorm understand the connection between `options` in **main.js** and `self.options` in **content.js** without adding executable lines of JavaScript.

```
var options = {
    name: "John Smith";
};

exportOptions(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding JSDoc with @lends tag before the object is enough:

```
exportOptions(/** @lends context.options */ {
    name: "John Smith"
});
```